# Computing beta distributions for multiple combinations

Tags: r, density-plot, beta-distribution

My data table which has 60 records* 3 fields, where: 
Each record represents a time stamp (t=1 till t=60) 
For each time stamp, we have 2 fields- the count of successes and failures based on roughly 500 turns.
e.g., 
 for t =1, there are 430 successes and 70 failures 
For t =2, there are 410 successes and 80 failures, and so on.
I aim to:
1.Create & visually compare the density functions for the 60 timestamps in a single plot.
2.Compute to probability of the true success rate being >=0.85 for each t.
How do I do this for all timestamps at one go in R , without having to run the same functions (see below) 60 times? 
Example with a single case t=0 which has 430 successes and 70 failures

```
# Plot of β density for t=0
v1<- seq(0, 1, by=0.01)
beta_t1<- dbeta(v1, 431, 71)
plot(v1, beta_t1,
     type = "l")
# Probability of true success rate to be 85% or higher when t=0
1-(pbeta(0.85,431,71))
```

Comment: If you give your codes about the single case by showing your effort, people may help you about the multiple combination case. Also giving a toy data set will be good.

Comment: Thanks, edited based on your inputs. Hope it's added clarity to the queries.